# how to invoke ant property from groovy script

Tags: ant, groovy

I have ant property defined as:

```
<condition property="configuration.REPORT_DIR" value="${configuration.REPORT_DIR}"       else="results">
    <isset property="configuration.REPORT_DIR" />
</condition>
```

and later , indside groovy script i need value of this property, below definition not working:

```
<taskdef name="groovy" classpath="./groovy-all-X.X.X.jar" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" />
    <groovy>
        def destinationDIR = ant.project.properties.getReference("${configuration.REPORT_DIR}")
        ...
    </groovy>
```

any ideas, how to invoke value ?

Comment: Can you try: `def destinationDIR = project.properties."configuration.REPORT_DIR"`

Comment: Cool, added as an answer :-)

Comment: You should accept the answer as noted - just click on the checkbox!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

```
def destinationDIR = project.properties."configuration.REPORT_DIR"
```

Comment: how to set ant property fromy groovy script ?